# my inverse fft is different from the original fft in matlab

Tags: matlab, fft, complex-numbers

I am using Matlab to do a ground response analysis. I need to do an FFT of a ground motion acceleration, multiply some constant, then get its inverse FFT. However, it's not returning the original signal during the validation.

Can anyone pls help me? Thank you.

```
Y = fft(acc,N);
h=2*abs(Y(1:N/2+1));
F=1/dt;
f=F/2*linspace(0,1,N/2+1);
f=f';

acc_ifft=ifft(h,N);
time_ifft=[0:N-1]*dt;
plot(time_ifft,acc_ifft);
```

If I try to plot using Y, it gives the correct signal. But I have to multiply the values in h by a constant, so I need to work from h.

Comment: You remove half the data, then take the magnitude, before applying the inverse transform. Of course that is not going to work! `ifft(Y)` is the only way of getting `acc` back.

Comment: Is there a way for me to be able to multiply a value (which is a function of frequency) to the FFT before investing it again?

Comment: Yes, you can multiply the complex numbers, no need to take the absolute value. `ifft(H.*fft(f))`.